# Latest MiKTeX: suggestions on how to install new fonts using the MiKTeX Console

Tags: miktex, package-writing, miktex2.9

MiKTeX has changed its look by introducing the `MikTeX Console`:

[image]

In the past I have always updated and added fonts not included in the MikTeX distribution using the mask `Settings`, `Update` and `Package Manager`.

Now I don't understand the procedure for installing additional font packages  not included into the MiKTeX distribution (for instance, the `mtpro2` and `classico packages) using the MiKTeX Console.

Please can you help me and explain, step by step, how do I install these fonts using the MiKTeX Console?

Comment: You are asking (at least) two questions: how the new miktex console compares to the older miktex-settings and how to install a font like mtpro2lite. Better split this in two question. And please stop to complain only because something changed. Give the new console a chance.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm just anxious because I'm doing a very important job and I can not use the `MikTeX Console`. It was not a complaint but I panicked. Anyway I edited the question hoping it will be clearer and you can help me. I thank you in advance and I apologize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install mtpro2lite like this:

I assume that you have a folder with the mtpro2lite files with a content looking like this (the important folders are the tex, dvips and fonts folder):

[image]

I will assume that this folder has the name `mt-texmf`, it the name is different adapt the following description accordingly.

### Step 1

Create inside `mt-texmf` a folder `miktex` and in this folder a folder `config`.

### Step 2

Create a a new text file in your editor and add the line

```
 Map mtpro2.map
```

Save the file with the name `updmap.cfg` in the miktex/config folder you created in step 1

[image]

**Alternatively** call on a command line

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

and add the line there.

### Step 3

Open the miktex console (user mode is ok). Click on `settings` and then on the tab `directories`:

[image]

Click on the plus:

[image]

In the explorer then go to the `mt-texmf` folder and select it.
This will add the folder as a new root.

### Step 4

Go to the tasks menu and select the entry `refresh font map files`

[image]

### Step 5

Close the console and test the installation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$a=\int f(x)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Ulrike Fischer, I thank you immensely for your answer. I've just downloaded MikTeX and I'll try, hoping it's not very tired, your procedure. I will let you know. Meanwhile, positively vote your precious answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried, also, another solution: a mix between the procedure of the old and the latest MiKTeX using `MikTeX Console` and some indications of Ulrike Fischer's answer to install both fonts. **It is important to see, also, the comment in additions to my answer.**

### Step (1)

Download `mtp2lite.zip` and `classico.tds.zip` or `classico.zip` (this is a clone of Optima font) files from CTAN web site: https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite and 
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico.

After finish downloading the file, unzip the fonts distribution files in a temporary directory (for instance on the desktop). Inside the unzipped files, you will find the following contents for `mtp2lite` and `classico.tds`. It is precious to remember that the important files of the `mtp2lite` must to lie into the folder `texmf` (dvips, fonts and tex).

[image]

### Step (2)

In Local Disk (C:), create `C:\Local TeX Files`.
**Warning**: **It is important to choose an adapt name for `TEXMF` root directory where you can put these files**.

### Step (3)

From the temporary directory created in **Step (1)**, move the contents of the `texmf` folder of the `mtp2lite`, for instance, from the unzipped file into the C:\Local TeX Files. I have choosen the path: `C:\Local TeX Files\texmf`. Similary for the font `classico.tds` I have created another different directory: `C:\Local TeX Files\cl-texmf`.

[image]

### Step (4)

After, I have opened the `MikTeX Console` using it as Restart as administrator or in user mode. Clicking on tab `Settings`, tab `Directories` and on the plus symbol (cyan color shown with the orange arrow), it is possible to add Generic `TEXMF root directories`. It's easy to see two generic paths: `C:\Local TeX Files\texmf` and `C:\Local TeX Files\cl-texmf`.

[image]

We can verificate, also, into `MikTeX 2.9` at the path: `miktex\bin\x64\mo_admin` (it is an .exe, executable file), that exist, once again, the old mask: `MikTeX Option (Admin)`. Click on `Roots` tab and we have the same paths of the previous picture.

[image]

### Step (5)

Run Command Prompt program (Open Terminal window): the icon with the red frame in the picture (green arrow) of the **Step (3)**. After that, change the directory by running the command `cd\`. There, run the following command line: `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`.

[image]

### Step (6)

The command line will pop out an empty file in Notepad program named `updmap.cfg`. Add the following line inside the file: `Map mtpro2.map` and `Map classico.map`. Save the file and exit the Notepad program.

[image]

### Step (7)

In the Command Prompt program, run the following command line: `updmap`. This process takes, probabily, a long time.

[image]

### Step (8)

Next, in MiKTeX 2.9’s Settings (Admin) program, click Refresh (FNDB) (the option exist also on `MikTeX Console`, click on `Tasks` - Refresh file name database) and Update Formats buttons. Always in `MikTeX Console`, you can select Tasks menu and select the entry `refresh font map files`.

[image]
[image]

### Step (9)

After that, in the Command Prompt program, run the following command lines:
`initexmf --mkmaps` and after `updmap`.

[image]

### Step (10)

Repeat again the procedure of the **Step (8)** only, and `mtp2lite` with `classico` packages are available in your PC.

Comment: Well all ways lead to rome, but you are taking a long one. `initexmf --mkmaps` and `updmap` (step 9) are doing the same thing and overwrite the result of the `refresh font maps` call in step 8 and the `updmap` call of step 7.  There is no need to use `cd` in step 5. The name of the folder in step 2 doesn't need to be `C:\Local TeX Files\texmf`. (Almost) every folder name will work. I have the fonts in `C:\Users\XXX\TeX\mtpro2lite`.