# Installing mtpro2 (free) for Windows 8.1

Tags: mtpro

I spent many many hours, consulting many blogs and even answers in tex.stackexchange, trying to install mtpro2 into Windows 8.1 with the MikTeX is 2.9.6677. Unfortunately I have been able to do that. I would be very thankful if someone can please explain step by step how to install it assuming I don't know anything about MikTeX.

Thanks

Comment: does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420044/36296 help?

Comment: You can also check [this link](http://staff.iium.edu.my/farahain/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/How-to-Install-MathTime-Professional-II-correction.pdf)

Comment: Dear @samcarter: It works. Finally. Thank you very very much.

Comment: MO B this time :-) I agree with talented user @samcarter on the duplicate of the request from the OP mail. It is, in my opinion, to emphasize that both the old and the new procedure exist in the matter.