# Why can't MiKTeX find chess fonts?

Tags: errors, chess

I've just reinstalled MiKTeX. And I'm trying to use a chess font with either `skak` or `chessfss`. But either package raises the error

```
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK font 
SkakNew-Figurine could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the 
information to get MiKTeX going again: 
.../AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You 
may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

The log file in turn is not terribly illuminating, terminating with the lines

```
2018-05-22 14:51:30,072-0500 INFO  makepk - running: miktex-ttf2pk.exe -q -t 
SkakNew-Figurine
2018-05-22 14:51:30,337-0500 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font SkakNew-Figurine 
could not be created.
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you install `SkakNew`  and run `updmap` from the command line afterwards ?

Comment: No, I just hit compile in the ide and it pulled most the stuff automatically.

Comment: You have to refresh the type 1 fonts data base after it's installed. With the new MiKTeX console, open the `Tasks` menu and select `Refresh fontmap files` (both as administrator ans as user, I guess).

Comment: Yeah, that and updating all the packages (who knew there could be 104 outdated packages after a fresh install?) did the trick.

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff At the excellent answers of Bernard you can see this link of my previous question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console