# MiKTeX 64 bit Windows 7: No AppData folders

Tags: miktex

I installed MiKTeX 64 bit on Windows 7 (64 bit). The Admin panel show the following directories:

[image]

But the directories that are supposed to be in `C:\Users\username\AppData\` do not exist. (It may be the case that in the 64 bit version those directories are not used anymore; but then why are they in the Admin Panel?)

Further, I need to install the Minion Pro files and the related guide instructs to place certain files to certain directories. (For example to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MikTeX\2.x\fonts\type1\Adobe\MinionPro\`) What am I supposed to do now?)

Comment: I also have roots listed which actually don't exist. I wouldn't worry about it. If miktex needs it is will create it. For your fonts: Create your own folder (e.g. `mytexmf` somewhere outside miktex and put the files e.g into `mytexmf\fonts\type1\Adobe\MinionPro` and then attach `mytexmf` as new root by clicking on the +.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks. I assumed it was essential that those font files were in AppData folders.

Comment: No, normally files can be in any texmf tree. There only must be in the correct subfolder.

Comment: Here you can find more details always of the excellent user @UlrikeFischer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console

Comment: The AppData folder is invisible by default under windows. You can show hidden files and folders under your files browser settings. Futhermore you can reach this folder by typing %AppData% in the address line of your file browser.