# Help to solve the issue with re-install MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update

For reasons unknown to me I had to uninstall old MikTeX due to console problems after an update six days ago and with the recent installation of MiKTeX 2.9.6930 I have actually problems with compilation. I add images and errors. I have clean all with *CCleaner* and other programs and `regedit` registry manually, removing all residues from the previous installation and cleaned Appdata and removed manually MikTeX 2.9 manually. The uninstall icon was not present.
I'm very anxious about formatting.
I kindly ask for your precious help.

**First problem for `initexmf`**.

```
2019-01-15 20:06:42,701+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:06:42,702+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:06:42,702+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --update-fndb
2019-01-15 20:06:42,790+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:06:42,959+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:06:43,016+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:06:43,016+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2019-01-15 20:06:54,833+0100 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-01-15 20:06:55,620+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:06:55,621+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:06:55,621+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --mkmaps
2019-01-15 20:06:55,631+0100 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-01-15 20:08:36,118+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:08:36,119+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:08:36,119+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2019-01-15 20:08:36,145+0100 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-01-15 20:08:57,054+0100 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-01-15 20:10:34,266+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:10:34,267+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:10:34,267+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --update-fndb
2019-01-15 20:10:34,491+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:10:34,532+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.

2019-01-15 20:10:34,532+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:10:34,532+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:10:34,532+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 551
2019-01-15 20:14:54,228+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:14:54,268+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:14:54,269+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --update-fndb
2019-01-15 20:14:54,480+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:14:54,594+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.

2019-01-15 20:14:54,594+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:14:54,594+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:14:54,594+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 551
2019-01-15 20:31:44,034+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:31:44,063+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:31:44,063+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --update-fndb
2019-01-15 20:31:44,288+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:31:44,301+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.

2019-01-15 20:31:44,317+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:31:44,317+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:31:44,317+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 551
2019-01-15 20:36:34,643+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:36:34,643+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:36:34,643+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --quiet --update-fndb
2019-01-15 20:36:34,799+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:36:34,924+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:36:35,377+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:36:35,377+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2019-01-15 20:38:39,297+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:38:39,297+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:38:39,297+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf -u
2019-01-15 20:38:39,469+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:38:39,485+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:38:39,579+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:38:39,579+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2019-01-15 20:38:48,610+0100 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
2019-01-15 20:39:08,728+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6937 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
2019-01-15 20:39:08,728+0100 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2019-01-15 20:39:08,728+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf -u
2019-01-15 20:39:08,916+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:39:08,947+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:39:09,041+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2019-01-15 20:39:09,041+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2019-01-15 20:39:18,056+0100 INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0
```

**Second problem for `texify`**:

```
2019-01-15 20:06:41,846+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "2 domande aperte.tex"
2019-01-15 20:06:42,073+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-01-15 20:06:54,889+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf' to create font map files
2019-01-15 20:08:32,060+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "2 domande aperte.tex"
2019-01-15 20:10:32,409+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "2 domande aperte.tex"
2019-01-15 20:10:32,454+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-01-15 20:10:34,656+0100 FATAL texify - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.
2019-01-15 20:10:34,657+0100 FATAL texify - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:10:34,657+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:10:34,657+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 551
2019-01-15 20:14:52,735+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "2 domande aperte.tex"
2019-01-15 20:14:52,869+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-01-15 20:14:54,633+0100 FATAL texify - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.
2019-01-15 20:14:54,634+0100 FATAL texify - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:14:54,634+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:14:54,634+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 551
2019-01-15 20:31:42,068+0100 INFO  texify - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean "2 domande aperte.tex"
2019-01-15 20:31:42,480+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-01-15 20:31:44,388+0100 FATAL texify - Windows API error 1224: Impossibile eseguire l'operazione specificata su un file la cui sezione mappata dall'utente è aperta.
2019-01-15 20:31:44,388+0100 FATAL texify - Info: path="C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\e97fd10829234ff4e140154c5987356e.fndb-5", modeString="wb"
2019-01-15 20:31:44,388+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2019-01-15 20:31:44,388+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 551
```

**3rd problem:**
From the compilation of file .tex with TeXworks:

```
Remedy:%%%%%%%<---done!


Close running MiKTeX programs and try again.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log

For more information, visit: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-file-in-use
```

**4th problem with `miktex-mf`** :

```
2019-01-15 20:36:33,690+0100 INFO  miktex-mf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-mf.exe"
2019-01-15 20:36:33,721+0100 INFO  miktex-mf - running 'initexmf' to refresh the file name database
2019-01-15 20:36:41,487+0100 FATAL miktex-mf - The executed process did not succeed.
2019-01-15 20:36:41,487+0100 FATAL miktex-mf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe", exitCode="-1073741510"
2019-01-15 20:36:41,487+0100 FATAL miktex-mf - Source: 
2019-01-15 20:36:41,487+0100 FATAL miktex-mf - Line: 0
```

**5th problem with `miktex-pdftex`** :

```
2019-01-15 20:08:38,228+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - starting with command line: miktex-pdftex.exe --miktex-disable-maintenance --initialize --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --alias=pdflatex --job-name=pdflatex -tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-etex pdflatex.ini
2019-01-15 20:08:38,247+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2019-01-15 20:08:38,250+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-01-15 20:08:56,138+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - finishing with exit code 0
```

**6th problem?**

```
2019-01-15 20:06:57,824+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - starting with command line: mkfntmap --miktex-disable-maintenance
2019-01-15 20:06:57,831+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Parsing config file "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\updmap.cfg"...
2019-01-15 20:06:57,834+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Parsing config file C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/config\updmap.cfg...
2019-01-15 20:07:07,415+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\ps2pk.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:08,141+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\download35.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:08,225+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\builtin35.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:08,313+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:09,331+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_pk.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:10,305+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_ndl14.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:11,585+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:12,458+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:13,745+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Writing C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_ndl14.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:14,648+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Copying C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map
2019-01-15 20:07:14,648+0100 INFO  mkfntmap -      to C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:14,897+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Copying C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map
2019-01-15 20:07:14,897+0100 INFO  mkfntmap -      to C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:15,499+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - Copying C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map
2019-01-15 20:07:15,500+0100 INFO  mkfntmap -      to C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex.map...
2019-01-15 20:07:16,428+0100 INFO  mkfntmap - running: miktex-fc-cache --miktex-disable-maintenance
```

**Images:**

[image]
From TeXworks
[image]

Comment: Something locks the fndb. Check https://miktex.org/kb/fix-file-in-use and if this doesn't help, open an issue in the miktex issue tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With this MikTeX is a continue problem :-( every two months there is a problem into my PC. I thank you very very very much. Into my previous question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console for my opinion missing also two paths as into red rectangle of the figure to the step 4.

Comment: Well my miktex works fine. But try out texlive as an alternative.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm desperate and stuck with my book. Should I format it my pC? I now I have open  an issue in the miktex issue tracker https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/247

Comment: Why should it help? Drop miktex if you can't handle it and install texlive.

Comment: In one of the german groups someone resolved a similar problem by installing the "next" versions of miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I too have had to solve the problem with another recent version. I've never used TeXLive before and I'm on edge with the school with so much work to do.

Comment: Sebastiano, the fact that MikTeX does not work well does not mean that data or TeX files are lost. You can save them on a USB key or on an online storage site.

Comment: MiKTeX always say in guidance but single users ignore the advice to NOT install for admin use. You MUST do everything twice and I suggest exit and restart PC first THEN DO NOT OPEN EDITOR as files may be locked open by one blocking the other JUST OPEN MiKTeX-console. SO FIRST AS ADMIN do a full update go to TASKS update FNDB and font maps (watch for errors) DO THE SAME as user. NOW test the editor

Comment: @KJO Thank you so much for your invaluable suggestions. It seems that your solution is working. :-) Unfortunately I'm used to MikTeX, I'm with an old PC from 2004.

Comment: Don't use `texify` - it will hide all the valuable diagnostics from you

Answer (score 1):

***If you need to reinstall again consider a single user basic install.***

MiKTeX always say in guidance but single users ignore the advice to NOT install for admin use. You MUST do everything twice

On this occasion I suggested you

1) exit and restart PC first
2) THEN **DO NOT OPEN EDITOR** as files may be locked open by one blocking the other
3) JUST open MiKTeX-console. **SO FIRST AS ADMIN** do a full update
4) Go to **TASKS update FNDB and font maps** (watch for errors)
5) **DO THE SAME as user.**
6) NOW test the editor

Your directories are short since two are the same but those are the normal COMMON defaults just check they exist with the expected collections of files.

What may be missing from before is additional user defined directories like blah\blah\mytexmf

IF you had a GENERIC user texmf you may need to add that back.

Directories may differ for admin and user ? but I don't run in dual mode

Comment: Your suggestions were fantastic and I really appreciated your clear answer. Unfortunately I'm used to MikTeX, I'm with an old pc from 2004. I don't even know how TeX Live works. Everything is at its best. I was thinking about formatting the computer tomorrow :-( Eureka!!!!! Thank you very very much.