# texmaker does not recognize the new package

Tags: packages, miktex, updating

(See my working and system context below)

I have downloaded a package (genealogytree) and added it to the texmf folder in MikTex 2.9 in the appropriated subfolders.

1. Have run `initexmf --update-fndb` from the cmd
2. I added the path of the new package in texMaker configuration.
3. When I run pdflatex in my tex file, that have as second line the command `\usepackage{newpackagename}`

   TeXMaker tries to get the internet connection to download the package.

Clearly I get an error message, given I cannot do it (see below details of my system and working context).

4. the package itself works properly, because if I paste all its file on my tex file folder, TexMaker compiles pdflatex properly.

However, this is an un-efficient way to work, because I have to make several tex files with this package.

5. Also did try the same (unsuccessfully), by placing the package in a local texmf folder in my personal user folder.

So, my question is, what to do in order to make my latex system to recognize the path of the new package.

---

MY WORKING CONTEXT IS AS FOLLOWS:

- I am working with windows 8 system and running MikTex2.9 from TexMaker 4.2
- My internet service DOES NOT allow me to update or install NOTHING direct from the web.
- The package manager does not work, given that I can not have a TCP IP connection, and so I get the usual error message:

> MiKTex Package Manager Error Message “Couldn't connect to server”

- so, I cannot update and or re install the previous version.

## Edit:

My installed version is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.11.12) 14 FEB 2019 20:20
```

Comment: Did you refresh the MikTeX database after installing the package in your local texmf?

Comment: how should I do this?

Comment: click on `Tasks` button  -> `Refresh file name database`

Comment: Inded I did in the cmd initexmf --update-fndb

Comment: Do it with the console

Comment: Don't understand u. I typed in  the cmd "initexmf --update-fndb". Don't find how to refresh file name database with the tasks button

Comment: Here a screenshot of the console https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console

Comment: I don't have the console of MikTeX, and given that I can't upgrade or install I should need something to be done via the cmd

Comment: Which version of MikTeX do you have?

Comment: Can you download files with a download manager – say like Filezilla ?

Comment: That is what I did: downloaded the files, but once I have them in my computer how do I proceed in order to be recognized as a package?