# Using the clrscode3e Package in LATEX

Tags: packages

I would ask, in which folder in Win10 should we put clrscode3e.sty file?

cite`put it where it will be found when you run LATEX2`

Best regards,

Comment: The TeX FAQ has a page on "where LaTeX can find it": https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf. For one-off usage I usually put such files in the same directory as my `.tex` file. But if you want to use the file more regularly, you should use a local TeX live tree.

Comment: @moewe you mean folder: ..\MiKTeX\tm\packages?

Comment: Actually, scrap that. According to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clrscode3e the `clrscode3e` package is available in both MikTeX and TeX live. So just install the package `clrscode3e` via the MikTeX Console and you should be good. Don't try to download and install it manually by copying files into MikTeX-controlled folders.

Comment: @moewe File `mtpro2.sty' not found. \usepackage .....

Comment: Well, that is a different package. AFAICS `mtpro2` is *not* in MikTeX or TeX live. You have to get it from the developer directly. I expect that there is a installation instruction. Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419957/35864 can also help.

Comment: @moewe  perhaps only one question: how can we install .sty file in a simple way?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864